# Enum unknown value changes to null

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, swagger-codegen

I am working on writing a REST API POST call. I have an enum in the swagger document for a resource. The problem is when an unknown value of the enum in the json format is sent while calling the API, the value gets serialized to null.  I want to know how do I restrict it so that it does not change it to null.

I tried enabling and disabling the below property while creating a bean of ObjectMapper.

```
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL);
```

Also I tried adding below property too but it seems if we create own object mapper, this property is not used too.

```
   spring:
     jackson:
      deserialization:
       read-unknown-enum-values-as-null: false
```

The value when it does not match the value specified by the enum, gets converted to null via the code generated from swagger:

```
 @JsonCreator
public static MyEnum fromValue(String input) {
  for (MyEnum b : AddressRoleEnum.values()) {
    if (b.value.equals(input)) {
      return b;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

I don't want to throw any exception when an unknown value is sent from postman to create(Post call) resource. I just want it not to change to null. Please advice.

Comment: You could add `@NotNull` annotation to the member of MyEnum in your bean and add `@Valid` to your rest api post call.

Comment: I already have @Valid on the rest controller method.  The Enum code is generated by maven plugin,  I can't change that.

Comment: Then probably the simplest solution would be to check manually if the value is null and throw an exception.